# CPU profile of hermes / JSC on release apk of react native app

Tags: android, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, react-native-hermes

Is it possible to do a CPU profiling (Flame graphs and call stack measurements in chrome performance tab) of the JS runtime in a react native app (hermes or old jsc) which is run in a release apk. I know there are plenty of docs and links and articles for doing CPU profling on debug apks, and ive been able to do it successfully, but can the same be done for a release apk, by maybe adding a debuggable flag or profilable flag on the native side. The reason why im trying this, the release apk has more optimised code and will probably give a better picture of the flame graph than a debug build. Any pointers would help thanks.